# External OIDC provider with GKE

Tags: azure, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, openid-connect

I have two Kubernetes clusters in datacenters and I'm looking to create a third in public cloud. Both of my clusters use Azure AD for authentication by way of OIDC. I start my API server with the following:

```
--oidc-issuer-url=https://sts.windows.net/TENAND_ID/
--oidc-client-id=spn:CLIENT_ID
--oidc-username-claim=upn
```

I created a Kubernetes cluster on GKE, and I'm trying to figure out how to use my OIDC provider there. I know that GKE fully manages the control plane.

Is it possible to customize a GKE cluster to use my own OIDC provider, which is Azure AD in this case?

Comment: You mean, if your GKE cluster can use AAD for authentication?

Comment: @Hackerman Yes, I want to use Azure AD in this case, but it seems reasonable to expect that the solution would work for any OIDC provider, so I tried to keep the question general.

Comment: You can now do this with GKE:
https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/oidc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is now supported!  Check out [the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/oidc) on how to configure an external OIDC provider.

Comment: Didn't succeed to run on mac `gkectl create-login-config --kubeconfig bla`. Can I create this config in some other way, without `gkectl` which is only for linux?

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/anthos/clusters/docs/on-prem/1.8/downloads has a Mac version.

Comment: There is only `gkeadm` for darwin, but `gkectl` is for linux... Do I miss something?

Answer (score 3):

With GKE, you have no access to modify the API server outside of the cluster creation options. So you won't be able to configure this using the fully managed GKE product.

This would be worth submitting a [feature request](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) for though.